# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\xi x^{\alpha}}{ e^{x}-\xi} \:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am supposed to integrate for $\alpha \ge 0$
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{ \xi^{-1}e^x - 1} \:\mathrm{d}x,$$

where $\xi e^{-x} < 1$ which means, I want to express this in terms of simple functions (like the Gamma Function).

By using the geometric series I ended up with

$$\Gamma( \alpha+1) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\xi^n}{n^{\alpha + 1}},$$

but I am not sure if this is correct.

I.e.  I need an explicit way to write down this integral for $\alpha =3$, but I don't know how to simplify this.

Comment: Mathematica reports that: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\xi x^{\alpha}}{e^{x}-\xi}\:\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(1+\alpha)\operatorname{Li}_{1+\alpha}(\xi) = \Gamma(1+\alpha)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^{k}}{k^{1+\alpha}}$$ So you're correct.

Comment: Assuming Mathematica is correct.  But what the hell, it probably is!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> You did it right because

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_0^{\infty}{x^{\alpha} \over \xi^{-1}\expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x}
=\xi\int_0^{\infty}{x^{\alpha}\expo{-x} \over 1 - \xi\expo{-x}}\,\dd x
=\xi\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\xi^{n}\int_0^{\infty}x^{\alpha}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}x} \,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\xi\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
{\xi^{n} \over \pars{n + 1}^{\alpha + 1}}\int_0^{\infty}x^{\alpha}\expo{-x} \,\dd x
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\xi^{n} \over n^{\alpha + 1}}\Gamma\pars{\alpha + 1}
=\Gamma\pars{\alpha + 1}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\xi^{n} \over n^{\alpha + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\Gamma\pars{\alpha + 1}\Li{\alpha + 1}\pars{\xi}}\,,
\qquad\verts{\xi} < 1.
\end{align}

> For $\ds{\alpha = 3}$, the result is
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{3 + 1}\Li{3 + 1}\pars{\xi}=6\Li{4}\pars{\xi}}$. I guess that's all you can do about it.